# Trying to drop the two lowest values out of a list of integers, not sure how?

Tags: python, discord.py

Setting up a D20 game for discord using the discord.py rewrite. Setting up the 'dice' for stat initialization and wanted to change some stuff up, instead of doing `random.randint(1, 10) + random.randint(1, 10)` I wanted to 'roll' 5D6, then drop the two lowest values

I've just started researching how to do this, I can't find any examples for python logic that look useful, figured I'd ask the question.

```
values = [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6]
for x in values:
    dice = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5]
    for y in dice:
        y = random.randint(1, 6)
```

This is where I've gotten so far, I need to figure out how to drop the two lowest values, so I can continue the line and add the remaining three values of `dice` together

Actual: None at the moment

Expected: `dice` will return a value not less than three, but no greater than 18, that value will be applied to the first value of `values`, function will iterate through the list until complete and return `values` as a list of six integers not less than three but no greater then 18.

Comment: Sort the list, then slice it to remove the first two elements.

Comment: You might also consider using a list comprehension to generate the initial values like this: `val = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: Just use `dice = sorted(dice)[2:]`

Comment: @Bazingaa the sorted way is *O(nlogn)* the OP can be done in *O(n)*

Answer (score 0):

The built-in min() function can be used to isolate the lowest number.

Something like this would suffice for dropping the two lowest values out of your list

```
deletions = 0
while deletions <= 2:
    deletions +=1
    lowest_val = min(dice)
    dice.remove(lowest_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function returns the lowest number in a list. The standard [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.htm) function removes the item with a value of *x* (not the *x*th item) from a list. Combining these two, all you need is this:

```
import random
dice = [random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(5)]
print (dice)

dice.remove(min(dice))
dice.remove(min(dice))
print (dice)
```

Comment: that's more or less what I did, had to make a few more tweaks to get it to work for my purposes, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the tools provided by the [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module. The heapq module provides *heaps*, data structures whose first element is always the smallest<sup>*</sup>.

To get the result that you want, [heapify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify) your list and pop twice to remove the two lowest values.

```
>>> import heapq
>>> import random
>>> scores = random.sample(range(1, 7), k=5)
>>> scores
[6, 4, 3, 5, 2]
>>> heapq.heapify(scores)
>>> # First value is the smallest
>>> scores
[2, 4, 3, 5, 6]
>>> heapq.heappop(scores)
2
>>> # First value is the smallest
>>> scores
[3, 4, 6, 5]
>>> heapq.heappop(scores)
3
>>> scores
[4, 5, 6]
```

You could also use the [heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) function:

```
>>> scores = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]
>>> scores
[3, 5, 1, 4, 5]
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, scores)
[5, 5, 4]
```

<sup>*</sup> Technically this is a *min* *heap*; it's also possible to have *max* *heaps*, where the first element is the largest/greatest.